# How to convert a double to a C# decimal in C++?

Tags: c++, decimal, protocol-buffers

Given the reprensentation of decimal I have --you can find it [here for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371604/whats-the-best-way-to-represent-system-decimal-in-protocol-buffers)--, I tried to convert a double this way:

```
explicit Decimal(double n)
{
    DoubleAsQWord doubleAsQWord;
    doubleAsQWord.doubleValue = n;
    uint64 val = doubleAsQWord.qWord;

    const uint64 topBitMask = (int64)(0x1 << 31) << 32;

    //grab the 63th bit
    bool isNegative = (val & topBitMask) != 0;

    //bias is 1023=2^(k-1)-1, where k is 11 for double
    uint32 exponent = (((uint64)(val >> 31) >> 21) & 0x7FF) - 1023;

    //exclude both sign and exponent (<<12, >>12) and normalize mantissa
    uint64 mantissa = ((uint64)(0x1 << 31) << 21) | (val << 12) >> 12;

    // normalized mantissa is 53 bits long,
    // the exponent does not care about normalizing bit
    uint8 scale = exponent + 11; 
    if (scale > 11)
        scale = 11;
    else if (scale < 0)
        scale = 0;
    lo_ = ((isNegative ? -1 : 1) * n) * std::pow(10., scale);
    signScale_ = (isNegative ? 0x1 : 0x0) | (scale << 1);

    // will always be 0 since we cannot reach
    // a 128 bits precision with a 64 bits double
    hi_ = 0;
}
```

The DoubleAsQWord type is used to "cast" from double to its uint64 representation:

```
union DoubleAsQWord
{
    double doubleValue;
    uint64 qWord;
};
```

My Decimal type has these fields:

```
uint64 lo_;
uint32 hi_;
int32 signScale_;
```

All this stuff is encapsulated in my Decimal class. You can notice I extract the mantissa even if I'm not using it. I'm still thinking of a way to guess the scale accurately.

This is purely practical, and seems to work in the case of a stress test:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( convertion_random_stress )
{
    const double EPSILON = 0.000001f;

    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        double d1 = ((rand() % 10) % 2 == 0 ? -1 : 1)
            * (double)(rand() % 1000 + 1000.) / (double)(rand() % 42 + 2.);
        Decimal d(d1);

        double d2 = d.toDouble();

        double absError = fabs(d1 - d2);
        BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE(
            absError <= EPSILON,
            "absError=" << absError << " with " << d1 << " - " << d2
        );
    }
}
```

Anyway, how would you convert from `double` to this `decimal` representation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you guys will be interested in an implementation of a C++ wrapper to the Intel Decimal Floating-Point Math Library:

[C++ Decimal Wrapper Class](http://ofwlife.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/c-decimal-wrapper-class/)

[Intel DFP](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-decimal-floating-point-math-library/)

Answer (score 2):

What about using [VarR8FromDec Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221523.aspx) ?

EDIT: This function is declared on Windows system only. However an equivalent C implementation is available with [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/), here: http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/oleaut32/vartype.c

Comment: No, this is standard Windows. I thought you were running on Windows, without .NET

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for `System::Convert::ToDecimal()`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a69w9ca0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Alternatively you could try recasting the Double as a Decimal.

An example from the MSDN.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326763%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

```
// Convert the double argument; catch exceptions that are thrown.
void DecimalFromDouble( double argument )
{
    Object* decValue;

    // Convert the double argument to a Decimal value.
    try
    {
        decValue = __box( (Decimal)argument );
    }
    catch( Exception* ex )
    {
        decValue = GetExceptionType( ex );
    }

    Console::WriteLine( formatter, __box( argument ), decValue );
}
```

Comment: sorry but I'm using ansi C++.

Comment: @mister why: Why are you using Decimal, which is part of the .Net framework, but you are not able to use the .Net framework?

Comment: It's concerning C++/C# interop. Decimal is used in C#. Some types using Decimal are serialized through google protocol buffers and sent on the ESB.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have access to the .Net routines then this is tricky.  I have done this myself for my hex editor (so that users can display and edit C# Decimal values using the Properties dialog) - see http://www.hexedit.com for more information.  Also the source for HexEdit is freely available - see my article at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/HexEdit.aspx.

Actually my routines convert between Decimal and strings but you can of course use sprintf to convert the double to a string first.  (Also when you talk about double I think you explicitly mean IEEE 64-bit floating point format, though this is what most compilers/systems use nowadays.)

Note that there are a few gotchas if you want to handle precisely all valid Decimal values and return an error for any value that cannot be converted, since the format is not well documented.  (The Decimal format is aweful really, eg the same number can have many representations.)

Here is my code that converts a string to a Decimal.  Note that it uses the the GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library (functions that start with mpz_).  The String2Decimal function obviously returns false if it fails for some reason, such as the value being too big.  The parameter 'presult' must point to a buffer of at least 16 bytes, to store the result.

```
bool String2Decimal(const char *ss, void *presult)
{
    bool retval = false;

    // View the decimal (result) as four 32 bit integers
    unsigned __int32 *dd = (unsigned __int32 *)presult;

    mpz_t mant, max_mant;
    mpz_inits(mant, max_mant, NULL);
    int exp = 0;                // Exponent
    bool dpseen = false;        // decimal point seen yet?
    bool neg = false;           // minus sign seen?

    // Scan the characters of the value
    const char *pp;
    for (pp = ss; *pp != '\0'; ++pp)
    {
        if (*pp == '-')
        {
            if (pp != ss)
                goto exit_func;      // minus sign not at start
            neg = true;
        }
        else if (isdigit(*pp))
        {
            mpz_mul_si(mant, mant, 10);
            mpz_add_ui(mant, mant, unsigned(*pp - '0'));
            if (dpseen) ++exp;  // Keep track of digits after decimal pt
        }
        else if (*pp == '.')
        {
            if (dpseen)
                goto exit_func;    // more than one decimal point
            dpseen = true;
        }
        else if (*pp == 'e' || *pp == 'E')
        {
            char *end;
            exp -= strtol(pp+1, &end, 10);
            pp = end;
            break;
        }
        else
            goto exit_func;       // unexpected character
    }
    if (*pp != '\0')
        goto exit_func;           // extra characters after end

    if (exp < -28 || exp > 28)
        goto exit_func;          // exponent outside valid range

    // Adjust mantissa for -ve exponent
    if (exp < 0)
    {
        mpz_t tmp;
        mpz_init_set_si(tmp, 10);
        mpz_pow_ui(tmp, tmp, -exp);
        mpz_mul(mant, mant, tmp);
        mpz_clear(tmp);
        exp = 0;
    }

    // Get max_mant = size of largest mantissa (2^96 - 1)
    //mpz_set_str(max_mant, "79228162514264337593543950335", 10); // 2^96 - 1
    static unsigned __int32 ffs[3] = { 0xFFFFffffUL, 0xFFFFffffUL, 0xFFFFffffUL };
    mpz_import(max_mant, 3, -1, sizeof(ffs[0]), 0, 0, ffs);

    // Check for mantissa too big.
    if (mpz_cmp(mant, max_mant) > 0)
        goto exit_func;      // value too big
    else if (mpz_sgn(mant) == 0)
        exp = 0;  // if mantissa is zero make everything zero

    // Set integer part
    dd[2] = mpz_getlimbn(mant, 2);
    dd[1] = mpz_getlimbn(mant, 1);
    dd[0] = mpz_getlimbn(mant, 0);

    // Set exponent and sign
    dd[3] = exp << 16;
    if (neg && mpz_sgn(mant) > 0)
        dd[3] |= 0x80000000;

    retval = true;   // indicate success

exit_func:
    mpz_clears(mant, max_mant, NULL);
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: I definitely can't afford the cost of using strings to perform this conversion.

Comment: I didn't mean that you had to use it but you are welcome to.  If converting to string then parsing is too slow I thought you might be able to use some of the code.  The main problem I had was having to work with a 96-bit integer when the biggest the compiler provided was 64-bit (which is why I used the mpz_ routines - see http://gmplib.org).

Comment: I should also have mentioned that for when working with IEEE 64-bit numbers less than about 10e-10 there can be loss of significance.  For numbers less than 10e-28 false is returned (indicating an error) though just returning the System.Decimal representation of zero might make more sense.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

1)    sprintf number into s 
2)    find decimal point (strchr), store in idx
3) atoi = obtain integer part easily, use union to separate high/lo 
4) use strlen - idx to obtain number of digits after point

sprintf may be slow but you´ll get the solution under 2 minutes of typing...