# .NET decimal cross-platform standard

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

If I save C# decimal array to a binary blob with a binary writer, will I be able to seamlessly read this blob in Java or Python or R? Do these language have a corresponding data type or is there a cross-platform standard that .NET decimal adheres to?

I am converting all my numeric data to decimals before storing, because when an array of decimals is diffed and then compressed, the resulting blob size is much smaller for real world data than a float blob compressed by any algo (my tests show c.2x less space). And decimals do not lose precision on diffing. But I am not sure if I could read this blobs from any other language other than .NET ones.

I am reading [the wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point) but cannot answer this simple question myself.

Update:

Currently I take an unsafe reference to `decimal[]` array and cast it to `(byte* )` pointer, but this is equivalent to binary writer. The question is about cross-platform decimal interop, not serialization. See my comment in the first answer.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258313/conversion-bigdecimal-java-to-c-like-decimal help you?

Comment: How much data are you planning on storing?

Comment: @Oren all my data (gigabytes), chunked into small arrays and indexed for quik random access and wire tranfer

Comment: @ClickRick thanks, it helps. I think I could process raw bytes on the other end when needed, just like protobuf-net does before serializing

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for the `System.Decimal` type does not state what internal representation it uses (unlike `System.Single` and `System.Double` which use IEEE-754). Given this, you cannot assume that the raw binary state representation of any decimal number will be consistent between .NET Framework versions or even between physical machines running the same version.

I assume you'd be using the `BinaryWriter.Write(Decimal value)` method. [The documentation for this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d8bekdb(v=vs.110).aspx) does not make any statement about the actual format being used.

[Looking at the .NET Reference source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs,6a6c74c37c8d854c), we see that `BinaryWriter.Write(Decimal)` uses an internal method: `Decimal.GetBytes(Byte[] buffer)` which uses an undocumented format which might change in future or may differ per-machine.

However! The `Decimal` class does provide a public method `GetBits` which does make guarantees about the format of data it returns, so I suggest you use this instead:

```
// Writing
Int32[] bits = myDecimal.GetBits();

binaryWriter.Write( (byte)bits.Length );
foreach(Int32 component in bits) binaryWriter.Write( component );

// Reading
byte count = binaryReader.ReadByte();
Int32[] bits = new Int32[ count ];
for(Int32 i = 0; i < bits.Count; i++ ) {
    bits[i] = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
}

Decimal value = new Decimal( bits );
```

This approach uses 17 bytes to store a `Decimal` instance in a way that is documented and guaranteed to work regardless of the internal design of the `Decimal` type. 16 bytes store the actual value, and 1 byte stores the number of 32-bit integers needed to represent the decimal (in case the number ever changes from 4).

Comment: Thanks! `GetBits` is defined as `return new int[] {d.lo, d.mid, d.hi, d.flags};` and a decimal is a struct with sequential layout with an unspoken guarantee that the order of fields will not change, there is a comment in the source: `NOTE: Do not change the order in which these fields are declared. The native methods in this class rely on this particular order.` on line 142. So just taking an unsafe reference to `decimal[]` and treating it as (byte*) is not much different from your approach. On a receiving end at another platform I will still need a custom conversions from the 4 Int32