# C# Decimal to byte[] and back in C

Tags: c#, c

I have a system that stores a decimal value on a Mifare card

The C# decimal value is converted to a byte array of 16 bytes using this code

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memStream);
try
{
  try
  {
     writer.Write(m_Value);
     tmp = memStream.ToArray();
  }
  finally
  {
     memStream.Close();
  }
}
finally
{
  writer.Close();
}
```

which gives a 16byte representation.

Now we have a customer which needs to read and convert these 16 bytes back to a decimal number, **but in C**

How is this done ?

Can anyone find a definition/spec of the C# byte representation, i cannot

Comment: So you ask that we do your job ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28080198/5265292 good luck.

Comment: [Decimal floating point in .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) may help

Comment: Explain the requirement "convert these 16 bytes back to a decimal number, but in C".  C does not specify _decimal number_,  What do you mean by that?  do you want a `double`, an integer, a string?

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to use `MemoryStream`, `BinaryWriter`, etc, here; just `decimal.GetBits(value)` is fine. The contents are fully documented, here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits(v=vs.110).aspx. There is a constructor that *accepts* the same format.

Note that this gives you an `int[]`, not a `byte[]`, but... getting between `int` and `byte` is trivial; probably the easiest is to use shift and mask.

The `BinaryWriter` version is not officially documented, but is *probably* just the integers from `GetBits()` written sequentially.

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer? It was first to mention GetBits, which was OP's solution in the end.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why on earth would `GetBits` return an `int[]` when the expected implication of *`bits`* is, well, binary???

Comment: @IAbstract I guess you could argue that `int` are made of bits just as much as `byte` are... :) but: I fundamentally agree

Answer (score 0):

It is not good idea to rely on internal implementation of *System.Decimal* as far as it is a subject of change.

It is mach better to use **Decimal.GetBits**(value) that is well documented.

Other question is how are you going to pass you values to unmanaged code. For example, if you are using pInvoke you just pass decimal argument to method and it will be automatically marshaled to native code (if you want specify memory representation you can use [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] attribute).

As far as I know, C++ by default does not have decimal type.

However, if you really need memory representation of *System.Decimal* you can easily obtain it from source code:
[Decimal.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Decimal.cs) and [Decimal.cpp](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/classlibnative/bcltype/decimal.cpp).

Comment: Thanks. I have changed to the getBits() - the bytes are are passed from PC C# to an embedded C terminal using a Mifare 1K RFID card

Comment: New link to [Decimal.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Decimal.cs)