# Java BigDecimal , equivalent of C#'s Decimal(int[] bits) Constructor

Tags: java, type-conversion

I am trying to convert an input buffer (byte array) containing data that generated with a C# application to java data types. I have some issue with C#'s `Decimal` dataType.

C# example:

```
decimal decimalValue = 20.20M;
//converting a Decimal value to 4 integer vlaues
int[] intPieces= Decimal.GetBits(decimalValue); //{2020,0,0,131072}
//using native constructor to rebuild value
Decimal newDecimalValue = new decimal(intPieces); //20.20
Console.WriteLine("DecimalValue is " + newDecimalValue);
```

but there is no `Decimal` ( and also no Decimal(int[] bits) constructor ) in java.

C# [Decimal Constructor (Int32[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1de0ya1(v=vs.110).aspx) documention.

Comment: But a decimal is **not** a float... The bytes have a different semantical meaning.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so what is the equivalent ?

Comment: The corresponding type in Java should be `BigDecimal`, but I don't know if the bytes will match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java, you'd use `BigDecimal`. That's not quite the same type, but it's *reasonably* close.

You just need to reconstruct the 96-bit integer as a `BigInteger`, then scale it and optionally negate it:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] parts = { 2020, 0, 0, 131072 };
        BigInteger integer = BigInteger.valueOf(parts[2] & 0xffffffffL).shiftLeft(32)
            .add(BigInteger.valueOf(parts[1] & 0xffffffffL )).shiftLeft(32)
            .add(BigInteger.valueOf(parts[0] & 0xffffffffL));        
        BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(integer, (parts[3] & 0xff0000) >> 16);
        if (parts[3] < 0) // Bit 31 set
        {
            decimal = decimal.negate();
        }
        System.out.println(decimal);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
20.20
```

The masking when constructing the `BigInteger` parts is there to *effectively* treat the values as unsigned - performing a bitwise AND with a `long` with the top 32 bits clear and the the bottom 32 bits set, we're constructing the same numeric value you'd get by casting each `int` to `uint` in C#.

Comment: Can you add some explanation? I don't understand how `parts[3]` is processed, only that is represents the MSBs, because of LE encoding.

Comment: not working for big values, C# decimal 202020202020,2020 ( {-271981020, 470364, 0, 262144} ) returns 202019772523.4724 in java

Comment: Does anyone have an implementation for the conversion the other way around? So to convert a `BigDecimal` to the C# `int[4]` representation? That's definitely more complicated, with many more edge cases and different scenarios to cover. (Including when a `BigDecimal` doesn't fit into a C# `decimal`.)

Comment: @MarkVincze: Do you mean `BigInteger`? (I'm not quite sure where `BigDecimal` and `decimal` come into it...)

Comment: @JonSkeet I mean taking a `BigDecimal` in Java and converting it to the int array which can be serialized and sent to a .NET application (for example with Protobuf) where then the int array can be used as the argument to the constructor of the .NET `decimal`. (I started implementing it, but my brain hurts from trying to figure out how to handle the various `scale` and `precision` values correctly :))

Comment: @MarkVincze: There's a huge difference between `BigDecimal` in Java and `decimal` in C#: `BigDecimal` is *arbitrary* precision; `decimal` is *fixed* precision.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Some context as to why I'm trying to do this: we have many .NET and some Java services interoperating with Protobuf, all using decimal numbers to represent monetary values. And we chose to base our Protobuf decimal representation on the C# `decimal` (like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/371690/974733). But we'd like to have some `To` and `From` helpers implemented to be able to use these from Java (mapped to `BigDecimal`). Ofc we'll have to `throw` if it's out of range of `decimal` (but we're already using `NUMERIC` columns in SQL DBs, which has a range similar to `decimal`).

Comment: Maybe it'd be better to have an _arbitrary_ precision Protobuf representation? But then we'd have to validate the range and `throw` on the .NET side.

Comment: @JonSkeet if you're interested, I posted my implementation over at codereview.stackexchange.com: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/219675/convert-between-net-decimal-and-java-bigdecimal