# How to declare decimal object in gRPC same as C#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, grpc

We are converting our existing REST API service to gRPC core. While migrating existing classes understood that gRPC doesn't have a decimal datatype. We have a class in C# which is defined as

```
public class SalarySchedule
{
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SalaryDate { get; set; }
}
```

And we implemented this in the proto file as

```
message SalarySchedule
{
    // TODO: How to define this double to decimal
    double Salary = 1;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp SalaryDate =2;
}
```

For now, we have used **double** for **Salary** datatype. But this is causing a problem in internal calculations.

Can you please guide us, How can we define it as a **decimal in gRPC?**

Comment: https://visualrecode.com/blog/csharp-decimals-in-grpc/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371604/whats-the-best-way-to-represent-system-decimal-in-protocol-buffers

Comment: Do *not* use double for financials, but it sounds like you already know that.

Answer (score 6):

This question was answered by [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/protobuf-data-types#decimals).
Define a message DecimalValue:

```
// Example: 12345.6789 -> { units = 12345, nanos = 678900000 }
message DecimalValue {

    // Whole units part of the amount
    int64 units = 1;

    // Nano units of the amount (10^-9)
    // Must be same sign as units
    sfixed32 nanos = 2;
}
```

And then convert DecimalValue to decimal e.g. by using implicit operators:

```
public partial class DecimalValue {
    private const decimal NanoFactor = 1_000_000_000;
    public DecimalValue(long units, int nanos) {
        Units = units;
        Nanos = nanos;
    }

    public static implicit operator decimal(CustomTypes.DecimalValue grpcDecimal) 
        => grpcDecimal.Units + grpcDecimal.Nanos / NanoFactor; 

    public static implicit operator CustomTypes.DecimalValue(decimal value){
        var units = decimal.ToInt64(value);
        var nanos = decimal.ToInt32((value - units) * NanoFactor);
        return new CustomTypes.DecimalValue(units, nanos);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing, the link is not in english version though :P
here's an english version one: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/protobuf-data-types#decimals

Comment: thanks, the link is updated

Answer (score 3):

There was a proposed Money type that had some discussion, but hasn't gone anywhere as a "well known" protobuf type.

For now, honestly, I'd suggest just using `string`. I don't know whether you're using the Google implementation or protobuf-net.Grpc (which builds in it but allows "code first" usage), but if you're using the latter (protobuf-net.Grpc) and protobuf-net V3, you can use [`[CompatibilityLevel(...)]`](https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net/compatibilitylevel.html) to specify level 300 or above, and it will treat `decimal` as though it were a `string` for serialization purposes. If you're using Google's .proto approach, I'd apply the conversion manually, making sure to use an invariant culture.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation Marc. I am using  Google's .proto approach. If I go with string type and convert it manually, Wont it be an overhead on performance if I end up calculating huge collection?

Comment: @Oxygen you have that problem with any type in the Google implementation, since all `message` types become `class`, unless explicitly handled - which this isn't AFAIK; the `double` type is supported directly, but: is a terrible choice for monetary
 values

Comment: @Oxygen note: protobuf-net handles
 this *without* allocating (it handles the type internally), but: that is a non-trivial code-change

Comment: Use gRPC and handle types via strings like it's JSON. Why gRPC then?